# Excel Copy Formula Question

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

```
= MOD((B2 * (D1 - 1) ) + B3, B1)
```

If I copy this into another cell, it increases all the cell values by one. How do I go about either keeping all values the same? or being able to copy and allow only one vari to increase?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add a $ before the values

> = MOD(($B$2 * ($D$1 - 1) ) + $B$3, $B$1)

This would keep them all the same

The $ defines it as a fixed reference

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying and pasting the cell, copy the text formula from the formula bar and paste that into the new cells.  I believe that will allow the values to remain constant.